# Premailer.Net error: Could not load type 'AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser' from assembly AngleSharp 0.10.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, anglesharp, premailer

so I am using .NetFW 4.7.1 and I get the following error when Premailer.Net is being instantiated:

> Could not load type AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser.

I am using Premailer.Net v. 2.0.1 and AngleSharp v. 0.10.1.

Here is the chank of code that throws error:

```
public static string GenerateMail(GiftMailModel model)
{
     string htmlEmail = Engine.Razor.Run(GiftMailName, model.GetType(), model);
     return Finalize(htmlEmail);
}

private static string Finalize(string html)
{
     // Move Css to style attributes
     var pm = new PreMailer.Net.PreMailer(html);
     return pm.MoveCssInline().Html;
}
```

I get the exception on this line:

```
var pm = new PreMailer.Net.PreMailer(html);
```

I suppose this is an issue with AngleSharp version, maybe they got rid of `AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser`.

What do you guys think? Did anybody encounter this issue? If so how did you solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For who it may concern, here is the reason: https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net/issues/165

Comment: having the same problem, Any solution?

Comment: hey, we reverted it back to previous version. They have a bug in the version mentioned in title.